# how do I add a gem in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku

I updated a gem(rtf) in my ruby on rails app through the Gemfile. The app works fine on my localhost but when I pushed changes to heroku and tried 'bundle install' within heroku bash. I see that the gem has been installed based on the log

```
Using rtf (0.3.3)
```

Following this, I did a

```
heroku restart --a myapp
```

however, when i tried the app on heroku, it still cant recognize the lib installed through the gem, i get the following error(normally appears when the library cannot be reached for command "require 'RTF'").

```
cannot load such file -- RTF
```

What am I doing wrong in heroku?

Comment: apologies RTF is what I meant- have edited it in my question.

Comment: The docs (https://github.com/clbustos/rtf#some-examples) would suggest you should be calling `require 'rtf'`. I bet you're using OSX which has a case-insensitive filesystem (so it still works on your machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer by sevenseacat is right- i had just got the case wrong-

```
require 'rtf'
```

works fine. In OSX, it ignores case in the command require 'RTF'

Comment: Yes, but you should read up on Heroku dynos because your understanding of how they work is not correct.

Comment: yep- i agree, the gem was always installed

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how Heroku works. When you run a bash shell on your app, nothing you do on that dyno will affect any other dynos for your app (like your web dynos). Heroku runs bundle install for you when you deploy your app and if your Gemfile is configured correctly all the gems will be installed.